# Adding variables to a shell command in Automator

Tags: command-line, automator, path

I use Terminal to run a command. It runs fine from the command line, but I want to be able to automate it with Automator. The syntax of the command (of course, minus the quotes) is as follows:

```
 spotify-ripper user.name "/path/to/directory" "spotifyURI"
```

I've tried countless times to get Automator to:

1. Ask for finder items (to create the "path/to/directory")
2. Ask for Text (asking me to past in the URI/URL link from spotify)
3. Run Shell Script (/bin/bash)

   ```
   spotify-ripper user.name "$@"
   ```

I have tried it with "Pass input" to "stdin" or "as arguments". Just get an error. I've read that "$@" will pass both variables one after the other which just what I need. I've also tried "$1" "$2" as some posts have suggested.
What am I missing?
I just want to pass path info and a URL to the end of a shell command, but nothing seems to work. I've tried the GET and SET Variable options, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Anyone have any ideas what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. One way is already described in the question [Automator variable in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663982/automator-variable-in-shell-script) (make sure to enable the options *precisely* as follows):

1. Ask for Finder Items (Type: Folders)
2. Set Value of Variable (Variable [example]: Directory-Path)
3. Ask for Text (Checked: Ignore this action's input; Checked: Require an answer)
4. Set Value of Variable (Variable [example]: Spotify-Url)
5. Get Value of Variable (Variable: Directory-Path; Checked: Ignore this action's input)
6. Get Value of Variable (Variable: Spotify-Url)
7. Run Shell Script (Pass input: as arguments; Content: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; /path/to/spotify-ripper user.name "$1" "$2"`—change the "/path/to" part with the real path to spotify-ripper, of course: probably /usr/local/bin/spotify-ripper)

Another way is to use AppleScript, either in a "Run AppleScript" action in Automator or as an AppleScript application saved in AppleScript Editor. Here's an example in AppleScript:

```
on run
    try
        set spotifyDialog to display dialog "Enter a Spotify URL:" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK" cancel button "Cancel" default answer "https://" with title "Spotify Ripper"
        if the button returned of spotifyDialog is "OK" then
            set spotifyURL to text returned of spotifyDialog
            choose folder with prompt "Choose a folder:"
            set theDirectory to the result
            do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; /path/to/spotify-ripper user.name " & quoted form of POSIX path of theDirectory & space & spotifyURL
        end if
    end try
end run
```

Comment: that is amazing - but now just can't work out what the path to the application is. It was installed via Homebrew, so not sure where it was installed.

Comment: @MarkMonahan In Terminal, `which spotify-ripper` will tell you the path to `spotify-ripper` if it's in your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). If for some strange reason it's not in your PATH but you know it's in /usr, `find /usr -name "spotify-ripper" 2>/dev/null` should tell you the path also. If my answer above worked for you, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for all your input on this. To complicate matters, it continues to report an error with the shell script. When I run it through the Apple Script method above it says a required dependency is missing (Lame) and tells me to install it and add it to the PATH. Lame is already installed and works fine when spotify-ripper is run from the normal command line. Any ideas why it can't see dependencies when running through Apple Script?

Comment: @MarkMonahan AppleScript runs shell scripts using `sh`, which doesn't use the [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) from `bash` (the interactive shell in Terminal). If you installed `lame` with Homebrew, then in the AppleScript change `do shell script "/path/to/spotify-ripper user.name "` to `do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; /path/to/spotify-ripper user.name "` (changing the "/path/to" part, of course). That will tell `sh` where to find `lame`. If that doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Yes, lame was installed via Homebrew. Still can't get it work via Apple Script (I now get errors which seem more linked to Spotify-ripper having issues), but it now works in Automator when I add the PATH line to the "Run Shell Script" - I'll call that a success! Thanks so much for your patience and help

Comment: @MarkMonahan Yes, Automator uses `sh` to run shell scripts too, so it would need that PATH information for the same reason. Glad to hear that at least the Automator program works for you now. I will change the instructions in my answer, and perhaps you can mark it as "accepted".